Request was routed from a verified domain which is not CustomUrlDomain
I have a front door setup that has been working for many months. Now all of a sudden I am getting:"AADSTS399280: Request was routed from a verified domain which is not CustomUrlDomain."
Any ideas? I cant see any changes at all to any of the configuration or setup. This was working on Friday, and now on Monday its not.
The Setup:
I have a production Entra for my company that is on domain.com. To allow folks to login to my website on domain.com I have a second Entra for Customers configured to use my.domain.com. My website (Wordpress) then authenticates with mydomain.ciamlogin.com...I have a Front Door setup in ProdEntra to allow auth on login.domain.com for mydomain.ciamlogin.com.
The Problem:The route to login.domain.com results in "AADSTS399280: Request was routed from a verified domain which is not CustomUrlDomain." error.
Workaround:
On the auth, if I swap out the domain I can get it to work, so this does not work:
https://login.domain.com/658c1a65-f834-4a61-b64c-91b9a7b3e481/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=f18a31b9-50fb-45ea-ae5a-d904d0b19c67&nonce=66782fc4c344d&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fauth%2F&response_mode=query&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read+openid+email+profile&state=https%253A%252F%252Fdomain.com%252Fwp-admin%252F&response_type=code
But this does:
https://mydomain.ciamlogin.com/658c1a65-f834-4a61-b64c-91b9a7b3e481/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=f18a31b9-50fb-45ea-ae5a-d904d0b19c67&nonce=66782fc4c344d&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fauth%2F&response_mode=query&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read+openid+email+profile&state=https%253A%252F%252Fdomain.com%252Fwp-admin%252F&response_type=code
Questions:I would like to understand what the problem is, and how to fix it.

Has something changed in the way Microsoft configures these features?
Where do I find the CustomUrlDomain field?


What the problem is? -the request is being routed through a domain that isn't recognized as the custom domain configured in Azure AD B2C. Check Front Door Configuration. MS occasionally updates their services, but there have been no specific changes announced related to this issue. To find and configure the CustomUrlDomain- Go to Azure AD B2C in the portal.
Navigate to Custom domains under Customization.
Here, you can add and verify your custom domains.
